# How to build a hierarchical tree using EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, recursion, ef-code-first

I have the following code with which I'm trying to build a hierarchical / parent child relationship model using EF:

```
ICollection<Content> contentList = _dbset.Where(
                content =>
                content.CompanyId == companyId && content.ParentContentId == null && content.Deleted == false)
                .OrderBy(content => content.SortLevel)
                .Include(content => content.SubContent.Select(childContent => childContent.SubContent)).ToList();
```

How can I build a parent-child tree using EF in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EF tracks all objects loaded to the db context unless tracking is turned off on the actual query you can load all records you need to build the tree to the context and then write a linq query on the previous result set/collection to filter all the child->grandchild records by specify the parent id on the query. E.g

```
ICollection<object> treeList = <dbcontent>.<entity>.All().ToList();
treeList = treeList.Where(o => o.ParentId == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have an n amount of children who have more children? If you're not going to have *too* many of them, why not just have a recursive function?

The reason I'm asking if you're not having *too* many of them, you may get an exception if you recurse a function enough times eventually. But... that takes a lot of depth.

Comment: Correct. I could just write a recursive func but I don't have a definite amount of children which is my big concern.

Comment: Even so, I wouldn't worry about it so much unless you are hitting a few thousand children.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a try to a recursive Action through a fixpoint operator :

```
// static fixpoint operator (highly reusable)
public static Action<T> ActionFix<T>(Func<Action<T>, Action<T>> f)
{
    return t => f(ActionFix(f))(t);
}

// your recursive ordering
foreach (var parentContent in contentList)
{

  ActionFix<Content>(
     actionContent => 
           content => 
                {
                 // ordering on the subContent of the node
                 content.SubContent = content.SubContent.OrderBy(sc => sc.SortLevel).ToList();  
                 // recursive ordering on each element on the subContent
                 content.SubContent.ToList().ForEach(actionContent);
                })
  (parentContent);
}
```